# Azure AD B2C Audit Logs doesn't show custom attributes value changes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I've setup an editing profile user flow in AzureAD B2C with standard attributes (GivenName, Surname, DisplayName and Country) and also with custom attributes (e.g. VAT and FavoriteProduct).

After I run the user flow and modified the attributes values, I see the resulting audit log with the value changes, but only for the standard attributesv (GivenName, Surname, DisplayName and Country).

Is there a way to see also the changed values of custom attributes (in my case VAT and FavoriteProduct) in the audit logs? I need to collect them.

Also tried with a custom policy user journey, same result